# Exclude caching function with wp rocket

Tags: wordpress, caching

i'm using wp-rocket caching plugin in my wordpress website.
i have these functions for counting post views:

```
function getPostViews($postID){
$count_key = 'post_views_count';
$count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
if($count==''){
    delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
    add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
return "0 view";
}
return $count.' view';
}

function setPostViews($postID) {
$count_key = 'post_views_count';
$count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
if($count==''){
    $count = 0;
    delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
    add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
}else{
$count++;
update_post_meta($postID, $count_key, $count);
}
}
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'adjacent_posts_rel_link_wp_head', 10, 0);
```

but when i enable wp-rocket caching, post views doesn't counted. so here is the question: how can i disable caching for specific function ?

thanks

Comment: anybody nothing?

Answer (score 0):

You can't disable cache for a specific code on page.

The best way to manage that is to ajaxify `setPostViews` to `getPostViews` to cast and get post views on the frontend.